# One line tabular* entries have different indentation than two line entries

Tags: tables, spacing, alignment

Example:

```
    \begin{tabular*}{1\textwidth}{p{2.3cm} p{14.4cm}}
& I This line is short and doesn't have the indent \\[3pt]
& I This line is too long and has the unfortunate indent. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit... \\[3pt]
& I This line is short and doesn't have the indent \\[3pt]
& I This line is too long and has the unfortunate indent. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit... \\[6pt]
    \end{tabular*}
```

Result:

[image]

As you can see, the Ts in the first and third lines are to the left of the Ts in the second and fourth lines. How do I make it so that these Ts line up?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: The instruction `\begin{tabular*}{1\textwidth}{ll}{p{2.3cm} p{14.4cm}}` has faulty syntax. Try replacing it with, say, `\begin{tabular*}{1\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}p{1.5cm} p{7.5cm} @{}}` and recompiling the document. Next, the lack of alignment, as you put it, is due to the fact that the `p` column type performs full justification. If you don't want that, change `p` to `>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p`.

Comment: in general please always provide a small but complete example document that produces the output shown, presumably the fragment you do show writes the literal text `p2.3cm p14.4cm` into the first cell?

Comment: note there is no indentation here, each paragraph starts at the left margin, but that if you do use correct syntax and use p columns the inter-word spacing varies so the position of the T in the second word depends on the spacing required to justify the text in the paragraph.

Comment: I accidentally posted the code for one of my attempted fixes for this problem. I have now removed the ```{ll}``` in the OP.

Comment: but you have still not posted a complete document (as in Mico's answer)  doesn't really matter now as Mico has answered anyway but if you had posted the image based on a test document that you had code posted  then it would have been much easier to understand as then you have checked that the code actually is an example of the problem not unrelated errors.

Answer (score 2):

The reason the amount of interword whitespace differs between short and "long" lines is that the `p` column type performs full justification on the contents of the paragraph; depending on the available line break points, this can cause TeX to either shrink or expand the interword whitespace slightly.

If you don't want this, you need to turn off full justification, say by replacing `p{...}` with `>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{...}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{array}      % for '\newcolumntype' macro
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\usepackage{booktabs}   % for '\addlinespace' macro
\usepackage{showframe}  % add frame lines around text block

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabular*}{1\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} P{3.5cm} P{7.5cm} @{}}
& I This line is short and doesn't have the indent \\ \addlinespace
& I This line is too long and has the unfortunate indent. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit... \\ \addlinespace
& I This line is short and doesn't have the indent \\ \addlinespace
& I This line is too long and has the unfortunate indent. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit... 
\end{tabular*}
\end{document}
```